# angularjs state cannot be resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to load a new view upon a button click in my angularjs project. I have been getting this error.How to solve this? As i'm new to angularjs I want to I have given the state correctly in my app.js

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.compat', 'ui.router', 'testCtrl']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $stateProvider

                .state('app.registerPage', {
                    url: "/tp/AddQ",
                    views: {
                        'menuContent': {
                            templateUrl: "views/Registration_view.php",
                            controller: 'testCtrl'
                        }
                    }
                });


        $urlRouteProvider.otherwise('/AEAS/admin/');
    }]);
```

**first view**

```
<body>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-app="app">
        <div class="row">
            <form role="form" ng-submit="submit(data)">

                <h1>Welcome to Heart attack predictor!</h1>

                <div id="body">

                    <button><a href=""  ng-click="click();">Edit</a></button>

                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/Controllers/testCtrl.js"></script>
```

**second view**

```
<body>

<div class="container" ng-controller="testCtrl" ng-app="app">
            <div class="row">
                <form role="form" ng-submit="submit(data)">

                    <h1>Welcome to Registration Page</h1>

    <div id="body">

            <button><a href=""  ng-click="submit();">Edit</a></button>

    </div>
                </form>

</div>
</div>

</body>


<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>angularjs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/Controllers/regCtrl.js"></script>
```

**controller**

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', function testCtrl($scope, $state) {


        $scope.click = function () {

            $state.go('app.registerPage');

        };

    }]);
```

**ERROR**

```
angular.min.js:116 Error: Could not resolve 'app.registerPage' from state ''
    at Object.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.js:3179)
    at Object.go (angular-ui-router.js:3107)
    at m.$scope.click (testCtrl.js:8)
    at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.min.js:226), <anonymous>:4:206)
    at b (angular.min.js:124)
    at e (angular.min.js:268)
    at m.$eval (angular.min.js:142)
    at m.$apply (angular.min.js:143)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:268)
    at Pf (angular.min.js:36)
```

Comment: angular.min.js:116 Error: Could not resolve 'registerPage' from state ''

Answer (score 0):

You create a stateless view, so, angular can't "jump" from your view to `app.registerPage` state. I think you need to create a base(home, index) state and point it to your first view.

```
 .state('home', 
         {
            url: "/",
            templateUrl:'views/your_first_view.html',
            controller: "testCtrl"
         });
```

Also, you need to delete `ng-controller="testCtrl"` from your first view div.

Comment: you mean I have to change 'app.registerPage' to just 'registerPage'. I've tried that.still no luck

Comment: @CraZyDroiD but did u change your $state.go call as well ?

Comment: @CraZyDroiD can u post a screenshot from your browser console ?

Comment: I have included in my question. can u please take a look

Comment: can u please show me an example on creating a base?

Comment: when you said delete ng-controller ="testCtrl" I found out what was the problem. Eventhough I load my app.js it hasn't loaded in to my application. I deleted entire code of app.js but nothing changed. Why haven't my app.js loaded into the application correctly?

Comment: if u are going to uses states, avoid to declare controllers within views.